# Why $ne: null returning the empty arrays?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I`m trying to return the arrays are that have contents but $ne: null or $exsists: true still returning the empty arrays..

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
email: String, 
password: String, 
googleId: String, 
facebookId: String, 
secret: Array
});

app.get("/secrets", function(req, res) {
User.find({secret: {$ne: null} }, function(err, secrets) {
if (err) {
  console.log(err);
} else {
  if (secrets) {
   console.log(secrets); 
    res.render("secrets", {
      secrets: secrets
    });
   };
  };
 }); 
});
```

I googled quite a bit about it and I do understand that $ne: null would return every document where the secret array doesn't exists, but if its an empty array then why? Any suggestion how to overcome this rookie problem? Im new here be kind! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `null != []`.
You will have to explicitly write your condition to handle both.

[$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) is for not in. So find users where secret value is not in the given array. The given array can hold your multiple values.

```
User.find({secret: {$nin: [null, [] ] } },...
```

Also, with `$exists` you will even get docs where the field is `null`. The only docs you will not get are the ones where the secret field does not exist at all.

Comment: Thank you Tushar! That was very helpful of you. I googled a lot but didn`t find the $nin. You solved my issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the documents contain values for the `secret` field that include missing/undefined, null, empty array, and populated array, you have a few options to only match populated arrays:

{$eval:{$gt:[0,{$size:"$secret"}]}}`- get the size for the`secrets` array, and only match arrays that are not empty.

- `{"secret.0":{$exists:true}}` - only match the document if there is a first element in the `secret` array (implicitly doesn't match non-array fields)
- If the elements in the `secret` array are all the same type, a type-based query can be used.  For example, if the elements in the secret array are strings, `{"secret.0":{$gte:""}}` will match any array whose first element is a string.  This could also be optimized by creating an index on `{"secret.0":1}`